# RequireJs in IE8: "no define call for.."

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, requirejs

I use RequireJS 2.0.4 for loading Java Script files.

It works properly in Chrome, Firefox and IE9, but wrong in IE8.

I set `true` value of `enforceDefine` config property.

And the error message was `no define call for ...`

Answer (score 0):

> This occurs when enforceDefine is set to true, and a script that is
>   loaded either:
>
> - Did not call define() to declare a module.
> - Or was part of a shim config that specified a global string property    that can be checked for loading, and that check failed.
>
> Or, if the error shows up only in IE and not in other browsers (which
>   may generate a Script error, the script probably:
>
> - Threw a JavaScript syntax/evaluation error.
> - Or there was a 404 error in IE where the script failed to load.
>
> Those IE behaviors result in IE's quirks in detecting script errors.
>   To fix it:
>
> - If the module calls define(), make sure the define call was reached    by debugging in a script debugger.
> - If part of a shim config, make sure the shim config's exports check    is correct. If in IE, check for an HTTP 404 error or a JavaScript sytnax error by using a script debugger.

Source: http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#nodefine

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't explain the IE8 IE9 difference